# Set drop shadow on Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to create a method that puts a drop shadown on a bitmap.

The code I have now isn't working for me, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static Bitmap addShadow(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int radius = Math.min(h / 2, w / 2);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w + 12, h + 12, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint p = new Paint();

    Canvas c = new Canvas(output);
    c.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);
    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    p.setTextSize(45.0f);
    p.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setShadowLayer(5.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, Color.BLACK);

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 4, 4, p);
    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);

    return output;

}
```